# How to write Espresso test for BiometricPrompt

Tags: android-espresso, android-biometric-prompt, android-biometric

I am new in espresso test and I wanted to write the Espresso test for BiometricPrompt which is Google provided API to authenticate the fingerprint.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Please provide more details with a specific issue

Comment: @PatelRomil -- I have implemented the BiometricPrompt API to authenticate the fingerprint for login in our app and now I wanted to write the espresso test to validate it. Is there any possibility to write the espresso test for the Google provided API(BiometricPrompt).

Comment: I had the same question myself. Guess it's one of those things you can't automate a test.